# Non-parametric joint difference in means between groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references, joint-distribution, f-test

**Background**: I want to test the difference in means between two groups along multiple variables. The approach I know is to run a regression where the group variable defining the populations is the outcome and the variables to be tested are the explanatory variables.
$$ 
G = \alpha_1  + \beta 'X +\epsilon
$$
and then perform an F-Test of joint significance on the vector $\beta$.

**Question**: Isn't imposing a linear functional function strange in such a context? And is there a non-parametric test of joint difference in means between two populations?

Comment: So something like a multivariate-equivalent if a t test (which definitely exist) .. but nonparametric? Why not use the same multivariate T statistic in a resampling test?

Comment: multivariate T-statistic would work as well. Do you know a reference on this?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution (there's a list of references) but the usual multivariate T stuff isn't nonparametric ... That's word 1 of your title, so presumably that was for a reason. Hence the mention of resampling